# How to set progress of seekbar to a specific position when it is seeking

Tags: android, kotlin, seekbar

I am trying to set seek bar progress to a pre-specified value from arraylist when the onseeking method is called, but here the problem is the seekbar is not seeking to the required position from arraylist and then bumps at it's max position.I'm really stuck any help will be appreciated.

This is my seekbar onseekchanged:

```
fun seekbarseek(){
        customseekbar.setOnSeekChangeListener(object : OnSeekChangeListener {
            override fun onSeeking(seekParams: SeekParams) {
                if (seekParams.progress<=progresslist!!.get(1))
                {
                   Log.i("seekpos:","0")
                    zoomin()
                    customseekbar.onSeekChangeListener = null
                }
                else if (seekParams.progress>progresslist!!.get(1)&&seekParams.progress<=progresslist!!.get(2))
                {
                    Log.i("seekpos:","1")
                    zoomin()
                    customseekbar.onSeekChangeListener = null
                }
                else if (seekParams.progress>progresslist!!.get(2)&&seekParams.progress<=progresslist!!.get(3))
                {
                    Log.i("seekpos:","2")
                    zoomin()
                    customseekbar.onSeekChangeListener = null
                }
                else if (seekParams.progress>progresslist!!.get(3)&&seekParams.progress<=progresslist!!.get(4))
                {
                    Log.i("seekpos:","3")
                    zoomin()
                    customseekbar.onSeekChangeListener = null
                }
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: IndicatorSeekBar) {
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: IndicatorSeekBar) {
                if (seekBar.progress<=progresslist!!.get(1))
                {
                    customseekbar.setProgress(progresslist!!.get(1).toFloat())
                    customseekbar.onSeekChangeListener = null
                }
                else if (seekBar.progress>progresslist!!.get(1)&&seekBar.progress<=progresslist!!.get(2))
                {
                    customseekbar.setProgress(progresslist!!.get(2).toFloat())
                }
                else if (seekBar.progress>progresslist!!.get(2)&&seekBar.progress<=progresslist!!.get(3))
                {
                    customseekbar.setProgress(progresslist!!.get(3).toFloat())
                }
                else if (seekBar.progress>progresslist!!.get(3)&&seekBar.progress<=progresslist!!.get(4))
                {
                    customseekbar.setProgress(progresslist!!.get(4).toFloat())
                }
            }
        })

These is my arraylist content:

progresslist!!.add(0)
            progresslist!!.add(calprogress+calprogress)
            progresslist!!.add(calprogress+calprogress+calprogress)
            progresslist!!.add(calprogress+calprogress+calprogress+calprogress)
            progresslist!!.add(calprogress+calprogress+calprogress+calprogress+calprogress)
```

This the method which i want to call when seekbar is seeked:

```
fun zoomin()
    {
        Log.i("zoominposition", zoomposition.toString())
        if (zoomposition == 5)
        {
            zoomposition = 4
            setfocus()
        }
        zoomposition++
       customseekbar.setProgress(progresslist!!.get(zoomposition).toFloat())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting max for your progress bar first

```
customseekbar.setMax(maxValue);
```

Then your `setProgress` will work

Comment: already did that still it doesn't help and the zoomin method is being executed multiple time when seekbar is seeked